# Scan all ip address on a network ARP/Ping

Tags: arp, ping, broadcast

I'm working on a program to discover all computer on a network.
What is the best way to do that

My network is 192.168.1.0
There are few machines on this network and i want to know their ips

Should i have to answer my Arp table of my computer or ping all the machines for responses one by one, or a broadcast maybe ?

Comment: Questions about programming and application development are off-topic here. You should as this question on [so] where there are many network-savvy programmers.

Comment: I'm more interesting by the theorical concept. I don't want a programming answer

Comment: You could try any of those for IPv4, but the ARP cache is probably incomplete. None of those will work for IPv6. This question has been asked and answered multiple times on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have control of the network, (you do have admin control of the network gear; otherwise your Q is off-topic here), just look at the ARP caches on the switch(es) and router(s). Any system that is actively using the network will be known to your network gear, even if it wanted to "hide" from discovery/probing from other workstations/systems/programs.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems in your case pinging 192.168.1.255 and checking  ARP table afterwards would show you the hosts. If your task is to discover pingable hosts.

Yeah, I forgot the IPv6...

Comment: This only works if the hosts will respond to ping. Many hosts can have a built-in firewall which will block ping.